# StackView inside StackView inside TableViewCell

Tags: ios, uistackview

I would like to have a StackView inside a StackView inside a Tableview to achieve that on the left an image is shown and on the right three labels. Each label can have 0 to n rows which should make the cell grow, while the image is of a fixed size. XCode is complaining about my construction. Is there something I'm doing fundamentally wrong? Please see my screenshot for details.

[image]

Comment: I guess the height of your cell and the sum of 3 UILabel's instrinsic height have some difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing fundamentally wrong, and those warnings are only Interface Builder trying to help as it finds that the current layout doesn't match the constraints.

Xcode can fix that automatically for you by adjusting the layout to suit the constraints: Click on the yellow warning icon and choose to fix issues:  the issues listed there should disappear and you might notice some minor adjustments to your layout.

Comment: No - XCode can't resolve it automatically. But I could remove them manually. Now my problem is that the linebreak for long texts is more or less randomly. Even if I change rowcount from 0 to 2 the labels just take one row an crop the end sometimes.

Comment: What happens when you ask Xcode to resolve them? Also do you have a constraint to make the StackView fill the entire content view, horizontally and vertically?